# VPN client DNS setup for maximum anonymity

Tags: privacy, vpn, dns, anonymity

I am installing a pivpn, on my raspberry pi, at my home network and it asks me for the **DNS provider** for my VPN Clients. I am concerned about the privacy of the DNS. What can I do to ensure the maximum anonymity of my vpn users. Some options I have already considered are:

1. using 1.1.1.1
2. using some free DNS like FreeDNS, DNS Watch etc
3. Google DNS (which I do **not** really want to use)

Please elaborate why your something you propose is better than others.

Comment: So you're running a VPN server on your home network, and your goal is maximum anonymity?   That only means the traffic is secured between the client and the pivpn server. Any traffic destined for the public internet will go out your ISP as if it originated from your home network. You aren't gaining anonymity when you're the only one on a VPN server. Anonymity comes from being one user in a sea of other users who are on the same service.

Comment: Hmm, I understand your point. What about the anonymity of the users connected to it? My main goal was to have a trusted connection when I will be away from home on other networks.   Anonymity of my/our traffic was something I thought of as I was setting up the pivpn. I will rephrase the question of it is misleading.

Comment: You could use your ISPs DNS server (which is what your home network uses by default) or you could go with one of the ones you listed.  1.1.1.1 has policies in place saying they don't log your IP, and has externt audits conducted to hopefully provide some extra evidence they're doing the right thing.